# How to access xaml propert in a different xaml file

Tags: c#, xamarin, mapbox

I have 2 two different xaml file such as about and addgeojson. First one (about) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myMapApp.Views.AboutPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:myMapApp.ViewModels" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Naxam.Controls.Forms;assembly=Naxam.Mapbox.Forms"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AboutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <local:MapView 
                    x:Name="map" 
                    x:FieldModifier="Public"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    MapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9" 
                    ZoomLevel="3"
                />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

I want to access mapview object which x:Name is map in addgeojson xaml file. about.map is does not work. How can i access to map property? I need to use map.functions in others file.

-- UPDATE --

Now, I created a view model. I used an Instance to getting values of map. I could access center, zoom vs properties from anywhere. Also, 'customMap2' has Functions property actually. But, it returns null except beginning of the programme. Therefore, I can not use these map functions from another files. I  want that user choose a geojson file from mobile and loads to map. What is wrong?

```
using Naxam.Controls.Forms;
using Naxam.Mapbox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace myMapApp.ViewModels
{
    public class mapPage
    {
        private static mapPage _instance = new mapPage();
        public static mapPage Instance { get { return _instance; } }

        public MapView customMap2 = new MapView
        {
            MapStyle = MapStyle.SATELITE,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            ZoomLevel = 3,
            Functions = MapFunc
        };


        private static IMapFunctions MapFunc { get; set; }

        public IMapFunctions GetFunc
        {
            get { return MapFunc; }
            set { return; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: don't directly manipulate a UI page from another page, that's a horrible design.  Use MessagingCenter to pass messages between classes that will drive UI updates

Comment: I need to access functions in 'map' prop. I wont change any UI. I just need to access functions in mapview which name is 'map'.

Comment: regardless, direct access of that sort is a horrible approach.  Use messaging center or some mechanism that does not tightly couple your views together

Comment: Okay, I added view model. I updated my question

Comment: how many times do I have to say "MessagingCenter"?